# Update all other tabs in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-mvvm

I am building TODO list app using MVVM architecture.
I have view pager with 3 tabs: Daily, Weekly, and Monthly.

When I edit a task from daily tab and save it to the database,I can see the updated task in the daily tab and it's working perfectly.

The problem is when I move to the Weekly and Monthly tabs ,where the task is not updated.
I need to refresh the calendar when there is a change in the tasks of the same day.
I am using Collapsible Calendar library ( https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Collapsible-Calendar-View-Android )

- I thought about using interface that whenever a task is updated I can update all the other fragments.
- I also saw some people suggest making a method in MainActivity and call it from any fragment I need but I don't know if its a good practice.

What do you think is the best approach to this problem? Thank you !

Comment: If you are using the same `ViewModel` in all 3 of your fragments & they are attached to the same activity, consider using an Activity scoped ViewModel & use those in all your fragments. All the fragments will get the same data. You can also return a `LiveData` via your `Dao` for observing data changes in the database.

Comment: That is a great idea to use 1 viewmodel for all the 3 tabs,I haven't thought about it,unfortunately, its too late because I am deep into the project .. But I will do that the next time for sure,Thanks !

Comment: No worries, but I do not think this would take much of a change. It would simply be replacing the `by viewModels()` with `by activityViewModels()` unless it's not that straightforward case with your implementation.

Comment: Best time to improve the app architecture is when you create it. Second best time is now :). This definitely sounds like a case for an activity ViewModel, and you will save yourself headaches in the long-run by converting it to use a more appropriate architecture instead of some other hackier solution. You can have *both* fragment ViewModels and an Activity ViewModel too.

Comment: @TylerV Thank you Tyler! I Agree. I am using viewmodel for each fragment(3) and 1 more for the activity. What are you suggesting doing? Thank you

Comment: Use the Activity ViewModel for things that need to be consistent/notified of change across all three Fragments. Put some relevant LiveData for that state and have the fragments observe that.

Comment: Thank you very much guys ! I give it a shot :)